# Not telling potential employer that I'm already serving notice period

Tags: job-change, notice-period

I initiated resignation workflow for my current job 1 month back (7th January). I'm currently serving the required two months notice period. 27th Feb is my last working day. I passed all technical interview rounds (all 5 of them) at some other company I applied to. On Monday I'll have to mail them my last 3 months payslips, negotiate salary and tell them the date of joining. They'll be asking about the notice period in current company. I'm afraid if I tell them that I'm already serving notice period, they might not make an offer or reduce the salary.

I currently work at one of the best software companies here. Overall I have 2 years of experience.
The other company that I might join is a mid size company. My current company is well established one.
My current job pays me a high salary but I wanted to change the (sub)domain I was working on (that wasn't possible in the current company). Moreover I din't like working with my current manager (never had an argument with him. It was just that I din't like how he used to treat his juniors like they're nothing). I even got a good rating this year. Overall, I still felt it was in my best interest to change job. So I put up the resignation, worked only 6 hours (minimum time required) in the office everyday and focused only on preparing for the interview (for different domain). It was easier to clear the interviews because during the 2 years at my current job, I had worked on several personal projects based on the new tech I wanted to work on.

This is also not the reason I told my new employer for job change. I told them that I wanted to work in a startup because I wanted to learn more.

1. Should I tell them that I'm currently serving notice period without having any offer from other companies? I fear I won't get an offer or get a lower salary if I do this because they might start doubting my abilities (why did he leave without an offer?).

or

2. Should I tell them I'll be joining after 2 months. (I'm not sure whether the service letter from my current employer will have the resignation submission date mentioned.) If it actually is mentioned in the service letter and the new employer actually sees it AND has some issues because of that, what implications it might have for me.

The second option gives me a time period of 2 months for applying to other companies in that time. I'll be having an offer from this 2nd employer and I might use that as the reason for leaving my current job to the 3rd employer. If I get an offer from 3rd employer as well, I have a choice to join 2nd or 3rd employer (problem solved).

The other things that might happen

1. Service letter doesn't mention length of notice period/date of putting up resignation.
2. It is not a big deal to them/they just ignore it.

Overall I feel that not telling them about the notice period is a better choice. I don't want to lose this job offer.

Please tell me your opinion. What should I tell them on Monday? Thanks.

Comment: Can they really ask for the last 3 months payslips - that contains personal information they may not have a right to... depending on location...

Comment: Please add a location. Where I am (in the UK) asking for my last three payslips is unheard of, and submitting them would get you into serious trouble with your previous employer.

Comment: If be very concerned about sending them 3 months of payslips. It's trivial to modify PDFs or other source documents to show that you make any amount you claim. It seems like they don't trust employees will tell the truth about their pay, but are also too stupid to open Photoshop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> On Monday I'll have to mail them my last 3 months payslips, negotiate salary and tell them the date of joining. They'll be asking about the notice period in current company.

You're overthinking this - they're asking about notice period because they want to know when you can start, and that's likely it. So when they ask about notice period, you can simply say:

> I should be available to start from the 1st March.

(Or whenever you want to.) Chances are they then won't push for your exact notice period.

The fact you've handed your notice in already does make negotiations tougher, but not in the way that you seem to be thinking.

The power you have in a salary negotiation is walking away. If walking away is generally going to be bad for you (because you have no other job lined up), then your negotiation position becomes a lot weaker than it otherwise might be.

Comment: thanks berry. I told them 1st April joining date and also got 33% salary increase. Still, if they found out on service letter about my resignation submission date, can it cause me any problems on the day of joining, assuming that I don't have one more offer from some other company by that time?

Comment: @CodeWriter Please can you tell What did you told , and how they reacted ?

Answer (score -2):

You can be honest about you are serving notice period and inform them a date you can join them. They will be happy to hear that you are in the midst of handover.  Then all problem solved and no more lies. During your probationary period if this job is not suitable then accept the next offer. Nothing wrong to have back up plan.